# atoi() in C saving zip codes

Tags: c, atoi

Using `atoi()` while reading from a file and it is dropping the first 0 in some of the zip codes, for example:

```
int x = atoi("06461");
```

seems to be saving `x = 6461`.  Is dropping non significant 0's part of the `atoi` function?

Comment: And how do you suppose an integer can store leading zeros?

Comment: A little tip: Don't store things like post-codes, phone-numbers and other things like that as a number. It will only lead to weird bugs in the end (http://thedailywtf.com/ is full of examples of these).

Comment: Sadly that is what the professor wants so my hands are tied on this one, I normally would not do that.  This is why it was tripping me up.

Comment: Methinks your professor may have been featured on thedailywtf.com at one time :)

Comment: @DaveSwersky, why? Professor made Zach bump into an issue that leads him to understanding the nature of numbers better ;-)

Comment: @Michael: DailyWTF might be no more generous to the professor than Dave, so the prof could get on it even if intentionally doing exactly what you say! Let's not forget that the default position on SO is that interviewers and academic instructors have no idea how to program until proven otherwise. Presumably because by the time a confused student makes it to SO, chances are either the prof was confused too or else the student will mis-report the instructions ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, true in every respect ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't drop zero. It stores the number. And as a number (decimal) 06461 and 6461 is exactly the same value. It's up to you how to *present* the number — with (`printf("%05d",zip)`) or without (`%d` in case of `printf`) leading zero.

P.S. Note, that c folks are mightily confused by leading zeros, they tend to see numbers as octal then.
P.P.S. And I fully support Joachim's comment to your question.

Comment: Wow duh, it's early in the morning haha, parseInt in java does the same thing I think, I should have known that. If I wanted to save the zip as an integer I guess it is always going to drop off the leading zero.

Comment: @Zach, the thing is, again, it does *not* drop off the leading zero. If you have 4 apples, is it 4 or 04?

Comment: I generally store my ZIPs as chars, especially if there is a chance of needing to store non-US addresses.  Postal codes in the rest of the world often include non-numerics.

Comment: @DaveSwersky, the Joachim's comment I support in `P.P.S.` is exactly about that. I just didn't want to take credit for it and referred to the original author. So yes, sure you probably want to store it as a string.

Comment: The `%05` is simply adding a zero to the front of the number if it is less than five digits long?  I know that you can truncate numbers this way in C, I am just checking on the functionality of that statement because it solved my problem but I want to know why. Yes I would love to store it as a string but I am not allowed to at this time.

Comment: Yes, `%05d` pads with zeroes to 5, check the documentation for `printf`-family functions. But listen to what Dave and Joachim say ;-) (oops, I see you do:))

Comment: @Zach: Nothing is truncating anything. "6461" and "06461" are two different ways to write the very same number. No change in the number is needed to go from one to the other, just a change in how you choose to express the number. The `atoi` function converts some text to an integer, which you can express any way you want. But what you have is some particular integer.